# Force JPA to accept foreign keys value and not only the entities

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

I imported some JPA model classes from a MySQL schema.

Here is one of the sample classes that are auto generated by JPA:

```java
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;


/**
 * The persistent class for the surveys database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="surveys")
@NamedQuery(name="Survey.findAll", query="SELECT s FROM Survey s")
public class Survey implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
    private int id;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="done_at")
    private Date doneAt;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Form
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="form_id", nullable=false)
    private Form form;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to User
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable=false)
    private User user;

    public Survey() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getDoneAt() {
        return this.doneAt;
    }

    public void setDoneAt(Date doneAt) {
        this.doneAt = doneAt;
    }

    public Form getForm() {
        return this.form;
    }

    public void setForm(Form form) {
        this.form = form;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

}
```

The problem of this JPA model is, it just accepts entities for the foreign keys. I mean here I have `form_id` and `user_id` as the foreign keys! However I don't have any set functions like the following:

```
public void setForm(int formId) {
    Form form = find from table forms with id equal to formId; 
    this.form = form;
}

or 

public void setForm(int formId) {
    this.formId = formId;
}
```

**How can I force JPA to generate such kind of functions also when it tries to import the schema!?**

**If it is not possible what are the best practices for extending the JPA model class?** I mean as it may happen in the future by changing of the database schema I need to import the JPA models again, maybe it is not a good idea to implement these functions by hand inside the JPA model and manipulate it by hand.

**Maybe you ask why do I need such kinds of set functions that accept ids instead of entities?**
*My program reads some mockdata and tries to fill the tables in the MySQL. The problem is in the mock data I have foreign key of the `User` and `Form` entities. They are already exist in the DB, and I don't need to create them again.*

Comment: Your entity generation tool isn't JPA, or even part of the JPA specification. It might have options to allow you to treat these foreign keys as just strings in your object model, avoiding the need for the lookup outright. Why issue an SQL query to fetch data you don't need? Map it as a basic if you don't need the object representation fetched, or want to control when it is fetched. If your tool can't handle it, remove the fk constraint in the database, generate your model, and then put it back.

Comment: Also note you can add a basic string mapping to your model yourself, you just have to decide which of the two are writable by JPA and mark the other as insertable/updatable=false.

Comment: I use eclipse and I just made the models by connecting to Database. Could you please support your comments with more details information. How can I activate the option that you spoke about?

Comment: If you are using Eclipse's Dali project for model generation, you'd want to tag your questions to get their attention. They are tools overtop JPA, not JPA providers. see https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/ If you are asking about my comments on mapping a field both as a OneToOne reference and a basic, there are numerous examples and comments all over. I have pointed others at this solution as it gives them a way to access the foreign key in JPQL queries without having to force a join on some providers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use FK-s in JPA as is. You can use JPQL/SQL to update the given row's field with the FK or you can create a service class, where you load the Form by id and then set it to the given Survey.
You should avoid to extend an auto generated class (and its agains Open-Close principle too).

Edit:
Create a class, for example FormService. There you can create a method and use Spring Data JPA, JpaTemplate, Plain JPA or other methods to retrieve the Form.
For example, with hibernate:

```
Form form = session.load(Form.class, id);
```

Then you set this to the Survey.

```
survay.setForm(form);
```

And now just save it back (persist if it is a new survey or merge if not).

```
session.merge(survay);
```

If you use Spring, it may easier and better to use Data Jpa or JpaTemplate, but the previous one will work with Hibernate (and other JPA implementations) in any java environment.

Comment: Any link or a sample regarding what you mentioned: `you can create a service class, where you load the Form by id and then set it to the given Survey`?

Comment: I edited the answer, please feel free to ask for another info if necessary.

Comment: Here I  found a full implementation fur such a service:

http://zetcode.com/springboot/findbyid/